# TeXstudio output in chrome after compile

Tags: output

i do not have pdf reader installed. i want my output in chrome after compiling my program in TeXstudio.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you tell us what operating system you're on?

Answer (score 3):

Just select *crome* executable in the TexStudio preferences:

[image]

> i want to view it in chrome when i hit F7 (view)

Then change the default viewer preference too:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
I followed the steps but it shows output in TeXstudio. When i click External Viewer icon then it shows it in chrome. i want to view it in chrome when i hit F7 (view)